# How to check to see if a random piece of an array is equal to specific array part?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to get my `String` array to get a random `String` from it and if it is a certain `String` then it needs to print an outcome in my text area.

```
String[] items = new String[]{"nothing useful", "trash", "a fork"};
```

Said array:

```
Random rand = new Random();
String outcome = items[rand.nextInt(items.length)];
```

Getting a random `String` from the array as a `String` named outcome:

```
if(outcome.equals(items[2])){
  textArea2.append("a fork" + "\n");
}
```

My attempt at getting it to put a `"a fork"` in a text area.
All of my text areas work so that's not my problem.

I've tried to use `.equals`, `==`, `if(outcome=="a fork")`, and various things like that without any of them working.

I need it to add `"a fork"` to the text area named `textArea2`.

Comment: The code you posted is correct. Your bug is located in the code that you're not showing. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: "a fork" gets  appended only when it gets randomly chosen. what is the exact problem?

Comment: Did you check the actual value of `outcome`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `if(outcome.equals(items[2]))` is even reached? Maybe there is something wrong with the trigger of your code. 
Just put something like a print in front of it to ensure it is really executed:

```java
System.out.println("if gets reached");
if(outcome.equals(items[2])){
    textArea2.append("a fork" + "\n");
}
```

As far as I can tell `==`, `.equals()` and even `if(outcome == "a fork")` should work in this case.